# C++ help...update text file?

Tags: c++

First of all, Im not too good at c++. so please take it easy on me.
I try to change the password but i only want to change a certain password in the text file.But when the text file got re-write like only one new password exits. the whole file got re-write.:(

user.txt

```
admin    openmyacc
guest    imguest12


void Passchange()
{
    string tempass;
    system("cls");
    cout<<"enter current password: ";
    cin>>tempass;
    if(tempass==inpass)
    {
        cout<<"utility to change password stored in file\n";
        cout<<"CHANGE PASS TO: ";
        cin>>user;
        ofstream Passfile("user.txt", ios::out);
        Passfile<<user;
        Passfile.close();
        cout<<"password successfully changed";
        getch();
        main();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an easy way to modify text in the middle of a file, although appending is easy. You'll need to read the old file and re-write it while detecting the old entry and replacing it with the new data.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a `"username<space>password"` format in your file with one line for each username?

Here is my suggestion:Write a function whic will work linke this:

1. Read all entries in the file in a loop and copy them to an array of
   strings(preferably two-dim array)
2. Search for a particular user in the
   array
3. If user is found change the password
   in the array
4. Clear the file
5. Write out the entire array in a loop
   back to the file